# how to force display all fixed width elements inside a div in a single line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have fixed width elements inside a div and i need to force all the elements to be displayed on a single line with horizontal scroll bar to 'grid-content'. I have tried many things but stuck.
Here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/29pobkzf/

Here is my CSS and HTML

```css
 .grid-container {
      width: 100%;  
      margin-top: 20px;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    
    .grid-content {
      width: 100%;
      height: 400px;
      float: left;
    }
    .grid-content .grid-row {
      width: 100%;
      overflow-x:scroll;
      border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    .grid-content .grid-row .grid-column {
      border: 1px solid #cccccc;
       display: inline-block;
      border-top: 0;
      border-right: 0;
      padding: 10px;
      height: 60px;
      width: 400px;
    }
```

```html
 <div class='grid-container'>
        <div class="grid-content">
                <div class='grid-row'>
                        <div class='grid-column'>a1</div>
                        <div class='grid-column'>a2</div>
                        <div class='grid-column'>a3</div>
                        <div class='grid-column'>a4</div>
                 </div>
        
        </div>
    </div>
```

My intention is grid-content to have a scrollbar and all its contents occupy a single line/horizontally aligned. The problem i am facing is some elements like a3 and a4 are getting rendered below a1 and a2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `.grid-column` are set to `display: inline-block;` and will wrap onto a new line by default. This behaviour can be changed by:

- Adding `white-space: nowrap;` to `.grid-content .grid-row`

You may also want to remove the white space between the `.grid-column` elements by either writing them out in one line in HTML (as in the example below) or by putting comments in between them. This will stop the white space from adding gaps between each `.grid-column` element in the resultant HTML.

```css
.grid-container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
.grid-content {
  float: left;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
.grid-content .grid-row {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.grid-content .grid-row .grid-column {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid-container'>
  <div class="grid-content">
    <div class='grid-row'>
      <div class='grid-column'>a1</div><div class='grid-column'>a2</div><div class='grid-column'>a3</div><div class='grid-column'>a4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `white-space: nowrap` in `.grid-content .grid-row` class so that it suppresses line breaks and remove `float: left` from `.grid-content`

[Read more about 'white-space' css property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Entire CSS can be replaced with the following:

```
.grid-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.grid-content {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid-content .grid-row {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.grid-content .grid-row .grid-column {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```